# Alternative to preloading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

So I'm trying to make a jQuery slideshow.

I've read many tutorials, and pretty much all of them say to preload the images using some variation of the code below:

```
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "02.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "03.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "04.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "05.jpg");
```

This is fine if you have four slides, however if the slide show has around 10 or 15 different slides, this can *greatly* decrease the speed of the website.

So the question persists, how can I get all of those pictures to the client and not cause such a big decrease in functionality?

Comment: If that method is slow, then AFAIK all methods of preloading will be, since all that method does is just load all the images into an array. You might put up a "Loading..." screen so the user knows that the page hasn't frozen.

Comment: Maybe you can preload each photo just before it will show up? In short: when photo N is appearing, photo N+1 will be preloaded.

Comment: you don't need to preload unless you want all the images visible first thing, as soon as the page loads. in a timed slideshow, that's never the case... it won't hurt to load the "next one" while you load the current one.

Comment: If you have a sideshow with photos in slider divs, all photos have to be loaded. That will definitely influence loading time/performance of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to preload only the image who will be next in the slideshow. Helpful link: http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you **don't need** to preload the images in javascript. It's all about user comfort. preloading images in javascript give you the ability of showing to the user some feedback (loading gif, loading bar, %...) and say to him : wait a few second please. Otherwise, he will see nothing during a 2 or 3s (depend of the number and the size of the images). For example, in a basic html page with images (with no js) all is working but it may take a while to load the page.

That's why jquery (and other) slideshow snippet use JS loading.